# Get check box list values in List using windows application in c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm working in C# on a Windows Forms application. I have one checkbox list and one ListView. I need to get the values of the selected checkboxes in the listview. I checked on the internet and I only got examples for ASP.NET but I didn't get any WinForms examples. Can anyone give me an example for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you tried please, we could perhaps build further on that.

Answer (score 0):

At first, this is a long explanation for you to understand what has to happen, below you'll find the short code that does the same.

Loop over your controls. If you find a checkbox, see if it is checked. If it is checked, add a listviewitem with the value of the checkbox:

```
foreach(Control c in form.Controls)
{
    if(c is CheckBox)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)c;

        if(cb.Checked)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(cb.Text);
            yourListView.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

With a bit of LinQ you can shorten this code to 2 lines. Loop over your controls that are checkboxes and are checked and add a listviewitem for each of them with their text-value:

```
foreach (var cb in form.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Checked))
    yourListView.Items.Add(cb.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1 :** You need to get the `CheckedItems` Collection from the `CheckedListBox` control using `CheckedItems` property.

**Step 2:** add  each `CheckedItem` into `Listview` using `Add()` method.

Note : From your Question `I have one checkbox list and one ListView` , i'm assuming that you have one `CheckedListBox` control and one `ListView` Control

Try This:

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Object chk in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                    listView1.Items.Add(chk.ToString());
            }
        }
```